# One time load Word2Vec from Memory

Tags: python, python-3.7, gensim, word2vec

I`m loading the Word2Vec models with the code below:

```
model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('cc.en.300.vec',binary=False,encoding='utf8')
return model.wv
```

It takes over 10 minutes every time it loads. I`m looking for a solution to run this code one time and call the cached result as much as I need to train a new model at the moment.

- Python: 3.7
- Gensim: 3.8.3

Comment: Maybe something in [the examples here](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html) will help.

Comment: You could try to `pickle` the model onto disk. Otherwise, if the file `cc.en.300.vec` is in text format, you could use `save_word2vec_format` to store them in binary form. Last thing to consider is the type of hard drive you're using. HDD or network drives have relatively slow reading speed.

Comment: Yes, I tried them but the problem is the final accuracy is lower than the full model version. I need the accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean it takes 10 minutes to simply complete the one line `.load_word2vec_format()`? Or to do additional operations on the loaded vectors?

I'd only expect mere loading to take so long if there's some problem like:

- You're using a machine with too little RAM to load the full model, so virtual memory is needed to just complete the reading. And if this is the case, further lookup/most-similar operations will also be very slow: typical access patterns for word-vector models need all words to be in main RAM memory. So you'd mainly get improvement if you either (a) move to a system with more RAM; or (b) use a far-smaller set of word-vectors, for example by only loading part of that `'cc.en.300.vec'` file. (The `.load_word2vec_format()` method can take an optional `limit` parameter to read only that-many vectors from the front of the file, and as such files put the most-frequent words up-front, using something like `limit=500000` doesn't lose much by discarding those more-rare words.)
- The filesystem volume from which you're reading is very slow, for example over a slow network link - in which case being sure to use a local hard drive, and best yet an SSD, could help a lot.

As user ~green绿色 comments, you might get some speedup from saving the model to a different format, such as by using `binary=True` option on a followup use of `.save_word2vec_format('cc.en.300.binvec', binary=True)`. However, this speedup would be fairly small, probably only noticeable if (as speculated above) a major problem is the slowness of the involved filesystem.

Another alternative save-format that could also offer a slight speedup would be to re-save in Gensim's native, Python-pickle-based format, like:

```
model.save('cc.en.300.kvmodel')
```

Then, a future load might again be slightly faster using:

```
kvmodel = KeyedVectors.load('cc.en.300.kvmodel')
```

(Note that if you're loading a static set of vectors using `KeyedVectors`, you **don't** need to use `.wv` to access/return the vectors. The `model` you've loading is already the set-of-vectors you need.)

Note that using a different storage format in these ways shouldn't affect the usefulness/quality of the vectors at all: done properly, they result in the **exact same** `KeyedVectors` object in memory. (If you've tried them & seen "final accuracy is lower", there must be some other error occurring.)

Further, is there any reason you're using an over-3-years-old version of Gensim (3.8.3 from early 2020), instead of a more-recent version, like the current 4.3.0 as of July 2023?

While I wouldn't expect mere `.load_word2vec_format()` to be very different in performance, other operations have been made more efficient (especially in memory use) since 3.8.3. And, other bugs that might bite your use have been fixed. So, it's usually better to use the latest releases – unless there's some really strong project-specific reason not to.

Finally, I'm a bit confused by your statement that you "need to train a new model". If you're talking about a new word-vector model, that'd be a totally-separate process from loading someone else's pretrained vectors (like `'cc.en.300.vec'`.

On the other hand, if you're using these vectors as contributing inputs into some other kind of model, perhaps as an interactive/investigational process, if you were doing something like a Python notebook, the `model` you've loaded will stay loaded in your runtime as you try many other things in subsequent cells.

So if you're paying the full loading cost repeatedly, as working on some other model, there may be other ways to change your workflow to truly use the loaded/'cached' vectors repeatedly. If you can say more about what you're doing with these vectors, and why one load isn't enough for multiple further steps, other suggestions may be possible.

Comment: Yes as you mentioned we are using Word2Vec to train a new sub-model with provided data based on this LLM. for more accuracy & reliability we need to find a way to cache the entire LLM model.

Comment: For the LLM model, managing its loading/memory-access-patterns is a separate question. But for a Gensim set of `KeyedVectors`, it's trivial: don't quit the Python runtime where it's loaded, it'll stay loaded in addressable memory. And make sure RAM is enough to avoid swapping, so the OS doesn't page it out.